# How do I add a user to groups by using the Bugzilla API?

Tags: bugzilla

Here is my code:

```
data = {
    'groups': [{'add':{'S8','ALL'}}]
    }
    r = requests.put(bugzilla_host + '/rest.cgi/user/user_name?token=' + token, data=data)
```

And I get the following error:

```
> {"error":true,"message":"Can't use string (\"add\") as a HASH ref
> while \"strict refs\" in use at Bugzilla/User.pm line
> 419.\n","code":100500,"documentation":"https://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/5.0/api/"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found i should change `data=data` to `json=data`